# Quantitative analysis Statistical test of Likert Scale to determine best option from multiple options

Tags: probability, likert

What is the best statistical test to be done to determine the best drawing of three drawings?

Given data collected from a Likert scale on various characteristics of the drawings. Questions on characteristics like Colours, size, brush stroke etc...
(Are the colours nice? Strongly agree, agree, neutral, disagree, strongly disagree)

People who are doing the questionnaire are divided into groups (City, age, gender, social class)

Top two boxes, top three boxes, bottom two boxes and bottom three boxes are also given.

So there are tables of data displaying the number of people who checked each box given that they are living in a certain city x and of age y.

Which statistical test can be used to determine the winning drawing using this data?

Comment: What is a Likert scale ?

Comment: @JeanMarie "Strongly agree, agree, neutral, disagree, strongly disagree"

Comment: It's a rating scale used in the survey.

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker You should have a look at the wikipedia article, in particular the "Composition" section, it's pretty clear: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale . Plus, beware of the difference between a Likert *scale* and a Likert *item*: https://www.john-uebersax.com/stat/likert.htm .

Comment: This is not something that statistical tests do. What you need is an index that is computed from the answers. But this has to be designed based on subject matter knowledge. There's no way to do this without knowing the questions. In particular you have to decide about the relevance of the questions regarding what you'd call "best drawing". I have no idea what city, age, gender, social class have to do with it by the way. The data cannot determine the relevance of the variables themselves, this has to be decided by you.